# Wrong battery percentage on ubuntu causes shutdowns when cable is unplugged

Tags: power-management, shutdown, laptop, battery, indicator

Ubuntu version 22.04
My battery indicator shows that my laptop battery charged only for 4% and it happens very often, I have dual boot with windows 11 and in my opinion it happens when I'm restarting my laptop to switch from windows to ubuntu.

It always shows very low numbers of percentage like 3-4% and never changes to a higher value acpi and upower shows just the same information

When I unplug my cable it shows that laptop will hibernate because of low battery and after cable plugged in it shows that cable is plugged but not charging

Everything working well on windows this problem happens only on ubuntu

Comment: How old is the computer and battery?

Comment: What is the laptop make/model/year, as this information will be useful in troubleshooting this issue (particularly as this issue seems to be hardware related). Thanks